# How do I disable a button in a table when all the controls in a row are disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to disable the Update and Opt-Out buttons when all the checkboxes in that row are disabled.

How to do this?

Here's a stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rt5vjc

Comment: why not wrap the contents of the onclick functions in if statements, no one would be the wiser.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't get you. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working stackblitz for the update button. Similar logic can be used on the Ot-out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p7lzrw?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

I have added a method in the typescript updateDisabled and that is bound to the disabled attribute on the button.